# How to fillup the holes at the time of object detection in GEE?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I permormed focal_max filter on my binary image on GEE but it not give me an output like python operator [scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html).

```
var training = filt.sample({
  region: area,
  scale: 30,
  numPixels: 10000
});
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(2).train(training);
var result = filt.cluster(clusterer);
print(result)
Map.addLayer(result.eq(1), {}, 'clusters');
var res = result.eq(1)
var kernel = ee.Kernel.square({radius: 3});
var opened = res.focal_max({kernel: kernel, iterations: 1})
Map.addLayer(opened)
```

How to perform [this](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html#image-segmentation) in GEE?